# Cannot open settings with Keyboard Shortcut Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.10

I set `Ctrl + 0` as Shortcut to Open Settings. and It worked Fine in Ubuntu 22.04.
After Updating to Ubuntu 22.10, it won't work.

If anyone could resolve the Issue. Please do. Thank you random citizen.

[image]

Comment: If you do not give more detail on how you set Ctrl+0 as shortcut to open sessions, we can note, but we cannot help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem so I added this as a custom shortcut using the command of `gnome-control-center` instead of having it under launchers as you have.